# how to tag list item

Tags: 2010, search, tagging

This might be a very basic question. I am looking for a way to tag list items in a SharePoint list.

Say I have a list with URL to amazon items. I need to be able to search those urls based on tags for those items.

I am hoping not to use SharePoint tag, but rather, add metadata to the list item to be able to search on those. But any suggestions are fine, I am kind of clueless here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 comes with Managed Metadata Services which does pretty much what you seem to be looking for. You would need to make sure is configured on your farm and then you can either define a Taxonomy via Central Administration or at the Site Collection Level only by creating TermSets to follow your hierarchies.

See here for an introduction http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-server-2010-HA101859256.aspx

You can create Site/List columns and add those to your lists that enable users to tag content directly when setting attributes.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 3):

One of many approaches to this question would be to create a simple Tag list.  Users can add tags into this list as needed.  Then in your list where you want to create a tag, create a Lookup column that allows multiple selections pointing to the Title column of the Tags list.

When items are created or edited, users can add or remove tags to the item from the tags list.  Search scopes can be created based on this column and utilized as well.

Answer (score 2):

While Managed Metadata is an excellent feature, it is only available in SharePoint 2010 Standard and Enterprise, not in SharePoint 2010 Foundation. Which version are you using?

If you are using Foundation, then PirateEric's answer will work well if the list of tags does not need to be edited frequently. If you would like users to be able to add their own tags,   include a column with a link to the referenced "Tags" lookup list and make sure everyone has contribute permissions to the list. This way of adding tags can be clunky and confusing for users though.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint ManagedMetaData fields are actually one of the best things about SharePoint 2010.  Just configure the ManagedMetaData Service, add a metadata field to your content type and you should have what you need.